# Django render doesn't seem to pass dictionary to template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, render

Update: I fixed it by uninstalling and re-installing Python/Django. Wasn't sure what was wrong.

I am trying to print out values from a dictionary to a html template using render (also tried render_to_response) but it doesn't seem to be working. The HTML template does not recognize any of the values I tried to pass into it.

Django code

```
def search(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    results2= [{'link':12, 'title':34, 'summary':56}, {'link':121, 'title':341, 'summary':561}]

    print results2  #is printed in command prompt, so this function is working
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'results2': results2}, context)
    #tried using render as well
```

HTML Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}


    <form class="form-signin span8" id="user_form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Display the search form elements here -->
        <input type="text" size="50" name="query" value="" id="query" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"    value="Search" placeholder="Put Search"/>
        <br />
    </form>        

    <p>{{results2}}</p>
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>{{link}}</p>
    <p>test2</p>

    <div style="clear: both;">
        <ol>
        {% for result in results2 %}
            <li>
                <strong><a href="{{ result.link }}">{{ result.title }}</a>                  </strong><br />
                <em>{{ result.summary }}</em>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </div>
```

In the command promp when the server is running and the function is called, it's printing 'results2', so the function 'search' is definitely working. However, the variables don't appear to be rendered.

View source for rendered page (equivalent to what's above):

```
    <form class="form-signin span8" id="user_form" method="post" action="">
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Y4PfA0x8jH67jWUlTJfjbMzk0EAouPrp' />
        <!-- Display the search form elements here -->
        <input type="text" size="50" name="query" value="" id="query" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" placeholder="Put Search"/>
        <br />
    </form>

    <p></p>
    <p>test1</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>test2</p>


    <p>test2</p>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <ol>

        </ol>
    </div>
```

So the list of dictionaries 'results2' is not being passed to the template. I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: The name for this data structure is "dictionary", not "library".

Comment: If you use django-debug-toolbar you get a sidebar where you can inspect the actual context that is passed to the template.

Comment: Should this really work? extending base.html, then adding code outside any {% block %} ? AFAIK that should let the code be unrendered. Check so you haven't copied base.html and the <ol> is in base.html too.

Comment: @krs It shouldn't. A block tag must be added to work. @SantoshGupta please show us your base.html. You should have a block tag like: `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

Comment: Or, better yet, for now take out the `{% extends %}` tag altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template expects results2 to be a list of dicts, while you're passing a single dict. Try something like `render_to_response('home.html', {'results2': [results2, ]}, context)`

Comment: Tried that. Also, changed library to a list of libaries " results2= [{'link':12, 'title':34, 'summary':56}, {'link':121, 'title':341, 'summary':561}]" . Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only for this template and are all the other templates working fine? If not, check up your settings file. Make sure that you have defined the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. It should look something like this..

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
'django.core.context_processors.request',)
```

Other than this, I don't see any other problem with the code.

Comment: I haven't tried another template, this is my first time ever trying to render a template.

Comment: Strange.. I haven't run the code but PyReda did and it worked for him. So, the only reason I see for this is some problem in the settings. Double check your settings. Also, check up the values of TEMPLATE_DIRS and TEMPALTE_LOADERS.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django are you running? If it's 1.8, the context processors were moved:

> Changed in Django 1.8:
>
> Built-in template context processors were moved from **django.core.context_processors** to **django.template.context_processors** in Django 1.8.

So in your settings file, under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, it should look like this:

```
(
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.template.context_processors.debug",
    "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.template.context_processors.media",
    "django.template.context_processors.request",
    "django.template.context_processors.static",
    "django.template.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

Comment: Using version 1.7.1.  The only thing in my settings.py related to context is "from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
'django.core.context_processors.request',)
"
from advice given on another comment here

Answer (score -1):

try to change your return statement like this,

```
return render_to_response('home.html', {'results2': results2}, context_instance = context)
```